# Transform matched group in sed multiple times

Tags: regex, sed

I have the following types of statements on multiple lines in multiple files (these are not necessarily on a line by themselves):

```
xref:my-awesome-link[This link]
```

I need to change this to:

```
xref:this-link[This link]
```

I have got to:

```
xref:this link[This link]
```

using (posting the whole thing which is inside a shell script):

```
find ./ -name "*.md.adoc" -type f -exec sh -c \
  'gsed -i "s/xref\:.*\[\(.*\)\]/xref\:\L\1\E\[\1\]/g" {}' \;
```

`xref\:.*\[\(.*\)\]` - the reg exp that captures the string inside [].

`\L\1\E\` - does the transformation for lowercase.

What I am struggling with now, is how to transform the **xref:this link[This link]** to **xref:this-link[This link]**. I know that I need to transform the matched group but haven't been able to figure out how to do both the lowercase AND replace the spaces with '-'.

I am running this on a MacOS using GNU Sed.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `gsed 's/xref\:.*\[\(.*\)\]/xref\:\L\1\E\[\1\]/g; :a;s/\(xref:[^[]*\) /\1-/;ta;'`

Comment: This works! Thank you.

For completeness, this is what worked:
`find ./ -name "*.md.adoc" -type f -exec gsed -i 's/xref\:.*\[\(.*\)\]/xref\:\L\1\E\[\1\]/g; :a;s/\(xref:[^[]*\) /\1-/;ta;' {} \;`

Comment: Glad it did,  I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
find ./ -name "*.md.adoc" -type f -exec gsed -i 's/xref\:.*\[\(.*\)\]/xref\:\L\1\E\[\1\]/g; :a;s/\(xref:[^[]*\) /\1-/;ta;' {} \;
```

I added `:a;s/\(xref:[^[]*\) /\1-/;ta;`:

- `:a` -  label `a`
- `s/\(xref:[^[]*\) /\1-/` - finds `xref:`, then 0+ chars other than `[`  (Group 1, `\1`) and then a space, and replaces with the Group 1 value and a `-`
- `ta` - a jump to label `a` upon a successful replacement

Answer (score 2):

Since you said your sed is gnu sed, this is an alternative solution using gnu sed's `e` flag instead of label and branch:

```
sed -r 's/(xref:).*\[(.*)]/echo "\1$(echo "\L\2\E"\|sed "s# #-#g")[\2]"/ge'
```

Let's do some test:

```
$ echo "xref:my-awesome-link[FOO Bar BLAH]"|sed -r 's/(xref:).*\[(.*)]/echo "\1$(echo "\L\2\E"\|sed "s# #-#g")[\2]"/ge'
xref:foo-bar-blah[FOO Bar BLAH]
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but a couple of questions. You said it is gnu sed but you used sed (my command had gsed, so just being sure). Further, you said to use the e flag, but your example doesn't use it. Finally, combining this with the find command is running into issues with quotes which I am trying to resolve but it seems that inside a bash script it gets tricky :)

Comment: @Dasher 1) about sed, you can get version info to decide which said do you have. You mentioned GNU Sed in your question. I have zero experience with MacOS. 2) `e` flag, I used it. pls check my command carefully, after `g` there is `e` 3) I cannot tell what is the cause of the quotes issue. But they can be solved by escaping parts correctly. btw, usually I prefer xargs with find.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for all your help @Kent and sorry for missing the use of the e flag. It helped me figure out what I was doing wrong. I will +1 your answer as this worked for me in the end with a few manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat ip.txt
xref:my-awesome-link[This link is good]

$ sed -E 's/xref:.*\[(.*)]/xref:\L\1\E[\1]/; :a s/ ([^[]+\[)/-\1/; ta' ip.txt
xref:this-link-is-good[This link is good]
```

`:a s/ ([^[]+\[)/-\1/; ta` is the main change. `:a` is a label to mark the substitution command that follows. `([^[]+\[)` matches a space character only if it is followed by non `[` characters and a `[` character (so this will fail if there are more than one `[` character in the line). Then, if the substitution succeeds, `ta` will be executed which branches back to the substitution command and this repeats until the substitution fails.

You can also use `perl` to do it in single substitution, as it allows Perl code in replacement section.

```
perl -pe 's/xref:\K.*(?=\[(.*)])/lc($1) =~ tr| |-|r/e'
```